# How work with PostGIS in Symfony 4 and Doctrine 2

Tags: postgis

I am looking to work with PostGIS in Symfony/Doctrine.
My search returns this old post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713508/how-do-i-use-doctrine2-to-work-with-geospatial-queries-using-postgis
The best result is: https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis
But I don't know in which file I must [register](https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis#setup) it ?

Other result is:
https://symfony.com/doc/master/cloud/services/postgresql.html
but as we can see in the path, it is for cloud (PaaS) Symfony

Could someone clarify?

Comment: Some information on what it is you are trying to do with these programs may help the community answer your question.

Comment: I have databases with geographic coordinates and need to show it on a map, allow search on it. I need to create a symfony  command to migrate from old databases to new one. My goal is to develop a back-end GIS "services" to serve my front-end apps.